When I'm going through app screens my variable is not working as intended?
I have this variable in one of my screens which it holds a boolean value:
final isAdded = ref.watch(cartProvider).contains(widget.coffee);

and I am using this variable to change the UI in some part of my screen:
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  isAdded
                      ? ref
                          .read(cartProvider.notifier)
                          .removeCoffee(widget.coffee)
                      : ref
                          .read(cartProvider.notifier)
                          .addCoffee(widget.coffee);
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (ctx) {
                      return AlertDialog(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        contentTextStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                        ),
                        content: Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6),
                          child: Text(
                            isAdded
                                ? 'Successfully removed from cart'
                                : 'Successfully added to cart',
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
                child: Container(
                  width: 300,
                  height: 65,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: isAdded
                        ? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error
                        : Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    isAdded ? 'Remove from cart' : 'Add to cart',
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 18,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),


when I go to other screens and I comeback to this screen, the value stored in isAdded variable is not valid I mean it has to be true but it is showing me false.
here is my riverpod provider:
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart' as sql;
import 'package:sqflite/sqlite_api.dart';

import 'package:coffee_shop_app/models/coffee.dart';

Future<Database> _getDatabase() async {
  final dbPath = await sql.getDatabasesPath();
  final db = await sql.openDatabase(
    path.join(dbPath, 'coffee.db'),
    onCreate: (db, version) {
      return db.execute(
          'CREATE TABLE cart_provider(id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, coffeeImage TEXT, CoffeeName TEXT, CoffeePrice REAL)');
    },
    version: 1,
  );
  return db;
}

class CartNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<Coffee>> {
  CartNotifier() : super([]);

  Future<void> loadCoffee() async {
    final db = await _getDatabase();
    final data = await db.query('cart_provider');
    final coffees = data
        .map(
          (row) => Coffee(
            id: row['id'] as String,
            coffeeImage: row['coffeeImage'] as String,
            coffeeName: row['CoffeeName'] as String,
            coffeePrice: row['CoffeePrice'] as double,
          ),
        )
        .toList();

    state = coffees;
  }

  Future<void> addCoffee(Coffee coffee) async {
    if (state.contains(coffee) == true) {
      return;
    } else {
      final db = await _getDatabase();
      await db.insert(
        'cart_provider',
        {
          'id': coffee.id,
          'coffeeImage': coffee.coffeeImage,
          'CoffeeName': coffee.coffeeName,
          'CoffeePrice': coffee.coffeePrice,
        },
      );

      state = [...state, coffee];
    }
  }

  void removeCoffee(Coffee coffee) async {
    final db = await _getDatabase();
    await db.delete(
      'cart_provider',
      where: 'id = ?',
      whereArgs: [coffee.id],
    );

    state = state.where((c) => c != coffee).toList();
  }
}

final cartProvider = StateNotifierProvider<CartNotifier, List<Coffee>>(
  (ref) {
    return CartNotifier();
  },
);

I tried initState() method to set the value of the isAdded variable in this way but I had some errors with that solution, now isAdded variable is defined in my build method.
if you need more information please tell me.

You are declaring: isAdded as final, The “final” keyword is used to declare variables whose values cannot be changed once assigned

still is not working, you know I had the same problem in another app , I think the problem is related to the provider. when I go to another screen and I come back, my provider is saving the data but i can not use that data in the entire of my app because each screen has its own widget tree

even though I am using provider scope

I'm really confused, this problem is very weird

Just to make sure the prblm is the dialog right? That's the place where value is not changing. But it changes on the second screen where you are using the provider ?

no, for the first time that i open the app everything is okay, when I go to the details screen which is the screen that I sent you, because the coffee has not chosen yet , the isAdded variable is false and when I press the button isAdded will be true because the coffee is added to my provider now everything is working properly but when I go to my cart screen where I am showing the coffees that are selected and I come back from that screen to my details screen I see that isAdded is false and I don't know why! in the isAdded variable I am looking at my provider

even though the coffee is added to my provider before, isAdded variable instead of showing true is showing false and I don't understand why

if you're confused too, I can put the codes on my github and share with you
